# Microsoft Graph API - OneDrive Sync Issues

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, postman, graph-explorer

I use this code to retrieve files from a OneDrive folder. It works perfectly, except for the fact that changes take a long time to propagate. For example if I delete a file, the response will continue to return that file for some 10 minutes. What am I doing wrong?

```
string endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UserId}/drive/root/search(q='.txt')?$select=Id,SharepointIds,WebUrl,Name,Size,FileSystemInfo,CreatedBy,LastModifiedBy";

var httpClient = new HttpClient {
    BaseAddress = new Uri(endpoint)
};

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(endpoint)) {
    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseModel>(json, options);
}
```

While I can reproduce this issue in Postman, Graph Explorer syncs within a few seconds. I have since discovered that the syncing issue resolves itself if I use Graph Explorer's access token.

Here is the endpoint I am using. I guess all I really need to know is how Graph Explorer generates its access token (or synchronization token?) in this situation.

```
string endpoint = https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Comment: So its a problem with token. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#code-flow. I tested the api with no delay in both VS and postman (in a personal app, I don't have spo lisence). Could you specify your scopes using. And how about using 'common` as the article instead of {TenantId}? Your have

Comment: @QiangFu I had tried both options without success. Scopes are set in Azure, but in any case if it was a permissions issue I wouldn't be seeing them at all. I have since found a solution, although given Microsoft's lousy documentation I can't be sure it's the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. All I needed to do is change the endpoint from:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UserId}/drive/root/
```

to:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UserId}/drive/root/delta/
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but Microsoft's documentation is pretty awful. I welcome any comments.